# How to return a variabel in Azure API function and read it via InvokeApiAsync function in Mobile app

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin, mobile

I want to return the name for the Blob created in Azure when calling InvokeApiAsync() in my mobile app

Function in Mobile app:

```
private const string PhotoResource = "photo";

public async Task UploadPhoto(MediaFile photo)
{
    using (var s = photo.GetStream())
    {
        var bytes = new byte[s.Length];
        await s.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(s.Length));

        var content = new
        {
                Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
        };

        var json = JToken.FromObject(content);

        await Client.InvokeApiAsync(PhotoResource, json);
    }
}
```

Azure function - run.csx:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, 
ILogger log)
{
    dynamic data = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
    string photo = data?.Photo;
    var imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(photo);

    var connectionString = 
        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageConnectionString"];
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount;
    CloudStorageAccount.TryParse(connectionString, out storageAccount);

    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    var blobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("beerphotos");

    var blobName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    var blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    blob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpg";

    await blob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

    log.LogInformation($"Blob {blobName} created");

    //return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    //NEW CODE ADDED AFTER ANSWER FROM JASON
    var response = req.CreateResponse();
    response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Content = new StringContent(blobName);
    return response;
}
```

If I try to write 
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,blobName);
I get this error: run.csx(35,16): error CS1501: No overload for method 'CreateResponse' takes 2 arguments

What do I miss in the azure function?

And how should the call of InvokeApiAsync() in my mobile app look like to read the blob name?

EDIT:

After adding new code in Azure function I get the following Unhandled Exception: 
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Input string '813255ca-02d0-4feb-8012-2d5a0ad49464' is not a valid number. Path '', line 1, position 36.

The exception is thrown when Client.InvokeApiAsync(PhotoResource, json) in the mobile function returns with the response. '813255ca-02d0-4feb-8012-2d5a0ad49464' is actually the name of the photo.

Comment: use the Body property of HttpResponseMessage

Comment: Thanks, but since I am new to this, it would be nice with an example ;-)
Any hints how to call InvokeApiAsync() in my mobile app?

Answer (score 0):

return the data in the body of the response

```
return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK) { Content = new StringContent(blobName) };
```

then when calling it

```
var resp = await Client.InvokeApiAsync(PhotoResource, json);

if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
  var guid = await resp.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but sorry for not posting enough code lines.
I am using

    var json = JToken.FromObject(content);
    await Client.InvokeApiAsync(PhotoResource, json);

And JToken does not contain a definition for "StatusCode" and "Content"

Comment: you need to assign the result of InvokeApiAsync to an object.  As I show in my example.

Comment: I am also getting this Unhandled Exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: e. Path '', line 0, position 0.

Comment: nothing in my answer has anything to do with json.  It doesn't appear that you are actually trying to do what I'm suggesting.  Please edit your OP to reflect what you';re doing and where the exceptions are occuring.

Comment: Sorry for not expressing myself clearly enough, but I have copied your example exactly as it is. The two code line were my old code.

Comment: so your original code has a json exception?  That is a different problem that you need to solve FIRST.  Most likely content doesn't contain a valid json string.

Comment: No, this json exception happens only when trying to return the blobName in the Azure function. I have now added the complete UploadPhoto function in the mobile app

Comment: but that is your original code without any errors?  Please post the code that generates the error, and indicate which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: I have update the Azure function with 4 new code lines. When the mobile function is my original code it throws an exception that the input string is not a valid number when InvokeApiAsync() returns with the response. Please see my updated post.

Comment: please include the stack trace for the exception

Comment: How do I best post stack trace at stackoverflow. Call stack doesn't show anything, so I try to post the output, but there is this limitation "Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 228930." when I try to edit my post.